# Why can I access seemingly arbitrary memory addresses in Python?

Tags: python, memory, numpy, cpython

Playing with [strides](https://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) in NumPy I realized that you can easily go past the boundaries of arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
>>> a = np.array([1], dtype=np.int8)
>>> as_strided(a, shape=(2,), strides=(1,))
array([  1, -28], dtype=int8)
```

Like this I can read the bytes outside of the array and also write into them. But I don't understand how this is possible.  Why doesn't the operating system stop me?  It seems I can go at least 100 KB away from this array, before a `Segmentation fault` is thrown.

The only thing I can think of is that this memory space is directly allocated by my Python process.  Does NumPy do this?  Is there a fixed size to this space?  What other objects can there be?

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray?

Comment: yep, doesn't explain this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different memory allocators in play here:

1. The operating system, accessible under Unix with e.g. [`brk(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/brk) or [`mmap(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).  This will generally give you exactly what you ask for, but it's not very user-friendly.
2. The C runtime heap, accessible with [`malloc(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and `free(3)`.  This may or may not return freed memory to the operating system immediately.  It may also round allocations up to the nearest page, if that is more performant.  This is usually implemented in terms of (1).

Most applications, including NumPy and Python, use (2) rather than (1) (or they implement their own memory allocator on top of (2)).  As a result, memory that is invalid according to (2) may still be valid according to (1).  You only get a segfault if you violate the rules of method (1).  It is also possible you are interacting with other live objects on the heap, which has a strong likelihood of causing your program to misbehave in arbitrary ways, [even if you are not changing anything](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx).

Comment: I think it is incorrect to say that segfault only results from violating method (1).  According to my own investigations (the answer below) it is only the memory maps that define when a segfault is thrown. Or am I wrong?

Comment: What about the guard pages?  I didn't quite get that.  Is it possible that although the OS has prepared a block for read access, an error could still be raised when reading is attempted?

Comment: @jasaarim: malloc uses mmap as well as brk.  Python uses malloc.  "Memory maps" are mmap, which itself is part of (1).

Comment: But otherwise I'll thank for the answer.  It was helpful and also made me think about the problem more.

Comment: oh, sorry, now I got it.  Yeah, you're probably right.

Comment: Also, sometimes newer Pythons seems to use mmap directly, at least for objects smaller than 512 bytes.

Comment: @jasaarim: It's possible Python is using an mmap for free lists or something of that nature, but malloc would be more sensible.  I suspect what happened is that Python did a large malloc, which was internally implemented as an mmap, and then carved off little pieces of it.

Comment: It's documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/c-api/memory.html#customize-pyobject-arena-allocator).  I understand that Python reserves a whole page with mmap and divides into small lots for all kinds small objects.

Answer (score 0):

Python and numpy is built with C, which has no memory protection built-in. Memory is allocated in the "heap" which is a large block of memory. Since all objects are allocated there, the memory area is quite large and filled with any kind of objects. Writing to this memory will probably crash your program.